# How can i deploy nodejs express typescript app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

I have a problem with deploying my nodejs application to Heroku.
i know that i can't push my application with index.ts i have to parse my code to js so i write the command "postinstall": "tsc" but it looks that is not works
When i try push my application to Heroku i get the information:

```
 > server@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_82163065
remote:        > tsc
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: tsc: not found
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote:        npm ERR! file sh
remote:        npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! server@1.0.0 postinstall: `tsc`
remote:        npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.T0pSN/_logs/2021-03-28T16_47_55_171Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.10.4",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: node dist/index.js
```

i have read tutorial from this site:
https://medium.com/developer-rants/deploying-typescript-node-js-applications-to-heroku-81dd75424ce0

Answer (score 1):

i installed typescript to dependencies and the application was successfully uploaded, but when i enter to my page i get Application error :( In the heroku logs --tail is the information:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at file:///app/dist/index.js:24:23
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=memories258.herokuapp.com request_id=6fed263e-7425-4c59-ac9a-8ad5f3fdbf88 fwd="193.192.179.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=memories258.herokuapp.com request_id=e45d9b0b-0974-44f5-9e36-c67d8989e446 fwd="193.192.179.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1):

finally its working now. I removed `"type": "module",` from package.json